# Pandas Merge Error: MemoryError

Tags: python, merge, pandas

## Problem:

I'm trying to two relatively small datasets together, but the merge raises a `MemoryError`. I have two datasets of aggregates of country trade data, that I'm trying to merge on the keys year and country, so the data needs to be particularity placed. This unfortunately makes the use of `concat` and its performance benefits impossible as seen in the answer to this question: [MemoryError on large merges with pandas in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199200/memoryerror-on-large-merges-with-pandas-in-python).

**Here's the setup:**

**The attempted merge:**

```
df = merge(df, i, left_on=['year', 'ComTrade_CC'], right_on=["Year","Partner Code"])
```

**Basic data structure:**

**i:**

```
    Year    Reporter_Code   Trade_Flow_Code Partner_Code    Classification  Commodity Code  Quantity Unit Code  Supplementary Quantity  Netweight (kg)  Value   Estimation Code
0    2003    381     2   36  H2  070951  8   1274    1274    13810   0
1    2003    381     2   36  H2  070930  8   17150   17150   30626   0
2    2003    381     2   36  H2  0709    8   20493   20493   635840  0
3    2003    381     1   36  H2  0507    8   5200    5200    27619   0
4    2003    381     1   36  H2  050400  8   56439   56439   683104  0
```

**df:**

```
    mporter  cod     CC ComTrade_CC Distance_miles
0    110     215     215     757     428.989
1    110     215     215     757     428.989
2    110     215     215     757     428.989
3    110     215     215     757     428.989
4    110     215     215     757     428.989
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
 MemoryError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8d6e9fb45de6> in <module>()
      1 for i in c_list:
----> 2     df = merge(df, i, left_on=['year', 'ComTrade_CC'], right_on=["Year","Partner Code"])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0rc1_309_g9fc8636-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
     36                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     37                          copy=copy)
---> 38     return op.get_result()
     39 if __debug__:
     40     merge.__doc__ = _merge_doc % '\nleft : DataFrame'

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0rc1_309_g9fc8636-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in get_result(self)
    193                                       copy=self.copy)
    194 
--> 195         result_data = join_op.get_result()
    196         result = DataFrame(result_data)
    197 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0rc1_309_g9fc8636-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in get_result(self)
    693                 if klass in mapping:
    694                     klass_blocks.extend((unit, b) for b in mapping[klass])
--> 695             res_blk = self._get_merged_block(klass_blocks)
    696 
    697             # if we have a unique result index, need to clear the _ref_locs

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0rc1_309_g9fc8636-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in _get_merged_block(self, to_merge)
    706     def _get_merged_block(self, to_merge):
    707         if len(to_merge) > 1:
--> 708             return self._merge_blocks(to_merge)
    709         else:
    710             unit, block = to_merge[0]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.12.0rc1_309_g9fc8636-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in _merge_blocks(self, merge_chunks)
    728         # Should use Fortran order??
    729         block_dtype = _get_block_dtype([x[1] for x in merge_chunks])
--> 730         out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=block_dtype)
    731 
    732         sofar = 0

MemoryError:
```

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: You seem to have duplicates in your `df` what happens when you drop the duplicates and then merge? `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`

Comment: They are not actually duplicates. df actually contains 93 columns, and each observation is unique to the year and trading partner. I only wanted to put a small subset of the data on SO to avoid confusion. Thanks for the idea tough! Also, the merge doesnt seem to be form lacking memory. When I do the merge it I dont utilize over 50% of my memory.

Comment: No worries, another thing to check which caught me out is if you have any NaN (null) values in any columns you are merging with, up to you what to do but I would drop these also if you have any

Comment: thanks! tried that as well.

Comment: Can you please try to put a breakpoint at the failing line and tell us what `out_shape` is?

Comment: @WesMcKinney, Thanks for taking the time to respond. `out_shape` is `[92, 32640825]`.

Comment: This out shape is incredibly bigger than my expectations. I expected a dataframe of less than 100 columns and less than 60,000 observations.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone coming across this question still has similar trouble with `merge`, you can probably get `concat` to work by renaming the relevant columns in the two dataframes to the same names, setting them as a `MultiIndex` (i.e. `df = dv.set_index(['A','B'])`), and then using `concat` to join them.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2], 'B':[2, 3], 'C':[3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2], 'B':[2, 3], 'D':[7, 8]})
both = pd.concat([df1.set_index(['A','B']), df2.set_index(['A','B'])], axis=1).reset_index()
```

**df1**

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
```

**df2**

```
    A   B   D
0   1   2   7
1   2   3   8
```

**both**

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   7
1   2   3   4   8
```

I haven't benchmarked the performance of this approach, but it didn't get the memory error and worked for my applications.

Comment: I am new to python and faced same issue, @Gordon Bean, please could you elaborate your method on concat, Thanks!

Comment: @omdurg - I added an example.