# Large csv pandas memory error

Tags: python, pandas, large-data

I'm running exactly the same one line code on two similar machines to read a 1 GB csv file.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('url_here', delimiter='|')
```

One machine reads it correctly, the other one gives me an empty memory error ("MemoryError:")

Both machines have 8 GB ram and an i7 processor.

What could cause this? Is there a way to increase memory availability for Python?

Thanks!

Comment: whats your `out_shape`? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085280/pandas-merge-error-memoryerror

Comment: what's your os and architecture? for both machines

Comment: Working machine:
Windows 8 (64b) laptop, iPython 1.0
Not working machine:
Windows 7, desktop, iPython 1.0

Comment: Sorry but, what's an out_shape?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `low_memory=False`:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('url_here', delimiter='|', low_memory=False)
```